# My Django project use Stripe payment gateway. how to remove billing address

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments

I am used Stripe payment gateway for get payment but checkout page get Billing address fields. how to remove this fields.
[checkout page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9PnY.png)

Here is my code:

```
checkout_session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
line_items=[
    {
        "price_data": {
            "currency": "usd",
            "product_data": {
                "name": "order",
            },
            "unit_amount_decimal": 5 * 100,
        },
        "quantity": 1,
    },
],
customer_email="test@gmail.com",
mode="payment",
success_url=success_url,
cancel_url=cancel_url,
```

)

Answer (score 1):

In stripe, you can get rid of frequently asked `billing address`, by

1. use `customer` field while creating sessions. This custom field expects a stripe `customer_id` like `cus_xxxxxxxxxxxxx` which is created as per this doc [creation of customer object](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/create).
2. You should add the address against the customer object created.
3. Once this `customer_id` is used in the session object, you won't find the form asking for the billing address.
4. If you follow the above steps, make sure you don't use both `customer` and `customer_email` while creating a session. Either of them should be passed. But passing `customer_email` will again provoke you to fill the address, so go with `customer`

Comment: I have change my stripe credential then try payment but now get Country or region field and default India selected, How to remove Country or region field.

Comment: so, the `customer_id` you have used while creating the session, check if you have saved the country or region detail. You get the field on your payment screen only when you haven't saved the country or region under your `customer`. So recheck once.